# Go Oracle not found?

Tags: go, installation

While setting up my new Go with Sublime I wanted to install Oracle tools with the following command

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle
  package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle: cannot find package "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle" in any of:
      C:\Go\src\golang.org\x\tools\cmd\oracle (from $GOROOT)
      C:\Users\User\Go\src\golang.org\x\tools\cmd\oracle (from $GOPATH)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the package link you'll see it throws NOT FOUND (package link [here](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle))

Based on [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18262), it seems that the package was renamed to guru, this is the correct installation:

`go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru`

Answer (score 0):

The command that works for me is:

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru
```

(the same as before, just with the new name of the tool - guru, instead of oracle)

Answer (score 0):

if %GOBIN% // $GOBIN is in your path, This command will be magic:

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/...
```